# How to share WiFi connection from a MacBook without being connected to internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, android, hotspot

I'm in the bush far from an internet connections, and want to stream Video from my Drone-controller (Android device) to a MacBook with and RTMP connection. For this to work, I need to get them on the same WiFi network. Android device may not have a SIM, so can't go into hotspot mode. Therefore, the MacBook must be the hotspot.

In MacOS Ventura, I've tried:

> Settings -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing -> "Share your connection from "Ethernet Adapter" to computers using "WiFi" -> "Start"

However, since (I'm presuming) the Mac is not actually connected to an ethernet adapter, it does not go into hotspot-mode, and no new network appears for my Android device to connect to.

I can do this if I have another Android device with a SIM card, but I'd like to avoid the need for a third device in this setup.

##### Is there any way to connect a SIM-less Android device to a MacBook over WIFI without an internet connection or additional mobile device?

Comment: Some progress - On the Mac you can create an ad-hoc network if you go "Wifi Settings -> Advanced -> Show Legacy Networks and Options" then "Wifi Icon on top -> Create Network (which should now be visible)..." 

This creates the network, and now the Android device can see it, but cannot connect to it - possibly because it is unsecured (and the Mac provides no option to create a password)...

Comment: For what you want to do internet sharing doesn't work. You actually need a router and connect both the same network.

Comment: Actually I did get it working using this answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343645/109904 , but the cure was worse than the disease in that it messed up my network settings on the Mac.  But it at least shows that their is a way.

Answer (score 2):

***CAUTION**: Adding the network service in the following step messed up with my network setting, making my apps unable to listen to ports on `localhost`.
If you added the network service this way, remove it with `sudo networksetup -deletepppoeservice "AdHoc"` and restart the computer fixed the mess for me.*

---

I had the same use case and found the solution in [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-create-a-secure-ad-hoc-network-in-macos/).

Essentially the steps are:

1. Create a new virtual network service using **Terminal**:

   ```
   sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice AdHoc lo0
   sudo networksetup -setmanual AdHoc 192.168.1.88 255.255.255.255
   ```
2. Use the **Internet Sharing** function to create new Wi-Fi network sharing the connection from the AdHoc service we created.

   On macOS Ventura the specific steps are as follow, other version of macOS may be different:

   - **System Preferences > General > Sharing**
   - Scroll to **Internet Sharing** and make sure its disabled
   - Click the ***i*** icon to config the ad-hoc network: share connection from *AdHoc* to *Wi-Fi*, click **Wi-Fi Options** to config the wifi network
   - Enable **Internet Sharing**

Comment: Outstanding answer. Good work!